# Difference between REST Client and browser

Tags: rest, browser

I wonder what is the difference between REST Client like Postman and browser? I want to make API calls but I don't understand why I have to use a REST Client instead of a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A browser permits to create simple GET calls, you invoke a url and obtain the response.

A REST Client permits more possibilities like:

- to construct every type of REST/HTTP call such as POST,PUT and DELETE,
- add headers to the calls,
- build a body for the calls (a json/xml or whatever of want one).
  It's a tool more sophisticated.

You can install a standalone one like:

- [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)
- [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/)

or install a browser extension for Firefox and Chrome like:

- [Resting](http://resting.owlcode.eu)
- [Rester](https://github.com/frigus02/RESTer)

Disclaimer: I'm the creator and maintainer of Resting